# What is going wrong when trying to apply a gabor filter to an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition, gabor-filter

I am trying to use a gabor filter on an image using a gabor function and parameters from a published object recognition paper. Instead of outputting the filtered image, the output image seems to be a portion of a white/gray circular gabor gradient in the top left of the image and the rest of the image is just black pixels. I have tried troubleshooting and I am not sure where things are going wrong. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Initially in the for loop I had:

```
output = gabor_output
if output > 0:
            output = output
        else:
            output = 0
```

That was resulting in all black pixels so I made the changes below in part of my attempt to troubleshoot. Ideally I would like the `output = output` (as above) rather than `output = 1` (what I have below). Here is the code I am trying:

```
# Gabor Function from S1 of "Robust Object Recognition" paper
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import math


orientation_1 = 0.0
orientation_2 = 45.0
orientation_3 = 90.0
orientation_4 = 135.0

def compute_x0(x, y, orientation):
    x0 = (x * math.cos(orientation)) + (y * math.sin(orientation))
    return x0

def compute_y0(x, y, orientation):
    y0 = (-x * math.sin(orientation)) + (y * math.cos(orientation))
    return y0

def gabor_function(x, y, orientation, wavelength, width, aspect_ratio=0.3):
    x0 = compute_x0(x, y, orientation)
    y0 = compute_y0(x, y, orientation)
    term_1 = np.exp(-(x0**2 + aspect_ratio**2 * y0**2) / (2 * width**2))
    term_2 = math.cos(((2 * np.pi) / wavelength) * x0)
    output = term_1 * term_2
    return output


# Trying it out

# Upload Image, convert to grayscale, convert to np.array
image = Image.open('/Users/damondtrowbridge/Desktop/MATLAB/Face.png')
bw = image.convert('L')
bw_array = np.array(bw) / 255.0

# Crop to fit different images and adjust for pooling
og_size = np.shape(bw_array)
Xdim = (og_size[0]//4)*4
Ydim = (og_size[1]//4)*4
cropped = bw_array[0:Xdim, 0:Ydim]

# Set up output array

out_1 = np.zeros((Xdim-3, Ydim-3))

for x in range(3, Xdim - 3):
    for y in range(3, Ydim - 3):
        gabor_output = gabor_function(x, y, orientation_1, 3.5, 2.8, aspect_ratio=0.3)
        output = gabor_output * cropped[x, y]
        if output > 0:
            output = 1
        else:
            output = 0
        out_1[x, y] = output



plt.imshow(out_1[:, :], cmap='gray', aspect='auto', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.suptitle('Filtered Image')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You’re not computing a convolution at all. This is not how you apply a filter. I would start by using a filtering function from a library.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have successfully used kernels for applying a filter, im just confused on  using a gabor function. This was the previous method I was using:
'''
# Center-Surround Kernel
kernel = np.array([[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 8.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0]])

# Apply the Kernel
for x in range(1, Xdim - 1):
    for y in range(1, Ydim - 1):
        region = cropped[x - 1:x + 2, y - 1:y + 2]
        difference = np.sum(region * kernel)
        if difference > 0:
            difference = difference
        else:
            difference = 0

        out_1[x, y] = difference '''

Comment: Gabor is just a filter. It is applied with a convolution. But it is a complex-valued filter, and the output is a complex-valued image. Typically you’d use the magnitude of that result.

Comment: For convolution use [`PIL.Image.filter()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.filter) or [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html). Don’t implement everything from scratch, use stuff that is already written and tested.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am trying to do as much as possible from scratch. I am getting a filtered image now but not the expected result. I implemented np.dot in my defined functions and made these changes in the loop: ''' region = cropped[x - 3:x + 4, y - 3:y + 4]
        gabor_output = gabor_function(region[3, 3], region[3, 3], orientation_1, 3.5, 2.8, aspect_ratio=0.3)
        output = gabor_output
        out_1[x, y] = (output + 1) / 2 '''

Comment: The Gabor filter is not 3x3. You need to sample the full kernel and use the full kernel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you! I am close but still not right. I tried to sample the whole kernel: '''for x in range(3, Xdim - 3, 7):
    for y in range(3, Ydim - 3, 7):
        region = cropped[x - 3:x + 4, y - 3:y + 4]
        gabor_output = np.zeros(region.shape)  # Initialize the output for the region
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(7):
                gabor_output[i, j] = gabor_function(region[i, j], region[i, j], orientation_1, 3.5, 2.8,
                                                    aspect_ratio=0.3)
        out_1[x - 3:x + 4, y - 3:y + 4] = gabor_output '''